# Cordova Speech Recognition Plugin

Tags: cordova, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am looking for a Cordova Speech Recognition Plugin that will work with latest version of Cordova and iOS 9, I have tried this one https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin and did not get much luck form it.

Does anyone know how to make this one work or have any other ideas?

Comment: With Cordova and Phonegap, it is best to ask the authors. Use the [issue tab](https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin/issues).

Comment: i agree with you @JesseMonroy650 and i have posted an issue for them, I did get it working somewhat. Just thought someone else may know on here.

Comment: Okay. It appears this is a beginners issue. Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post. I have a good idea what the issues is.

Comment: Not my first hybird app, Testing native on real device, CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to make it work, the API key was the issue. ISpeech offers a testing and production key. The testing key did not work and the production key worked, Going to say it's an iSpeech issue and have notified them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by using ng-speech-recognition AngularJS directive, it is compatible Cordova and works well on ionic, No need to install any plugins:

[ng-speech-recognition AngularJS Directive](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)